# Magento 2 Cadence Dedup The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am trying to execute the following commands in Terminal for Magento 2 found here https://www.cadence-labs.com/2017/11/magento-2-fix-duplicate-url-key-for-categories-and-products/.

```
cadence:urldedup:categories               Dedup Category url rewrites across stores
cadence:urldedup:products                 Dedup Product url rewrites across stores
```

However, it's returning the following:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

[image]

I googled a lot but didn't find anything relevant to this issue. If anybody has a solution to this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command like following in Magento2 root.

*php bin/magento cadence:urldedup:products*

It will work for you.